# How to pass parameter in onErrorResume from previous flatMap in Java reactor

Tags: java, reactor

I have below code

```
.map(agc -> new cTaskServiceCommand(or, agc, request))
.flatMap(command -> cTaskService.cTask(command))
.flatMapMany(event -> Mono.just(event).concatWith(Mono.justOrEmpty(event.getThrowable()).flatMap(Mono::error)))
.cast(orEvent.class)
.onErrorResume(throwable -> myFactory.createorEvent(or, throwable))
```

But I want to pass a parameter from command to onErrorResume like below

```
.onErrorResume(throwable -> myFactory.createorEvent(or, throwable, command.getName()))
```

How can I achieve this. Need to pass parameter from previous flatMap object to onErrorResume.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to look through the documentation, but found nothing obviously appropriate. Can only suggest such wrapping as a workaround:

```
.map(agc -> new cTaskServiceCommand(or, agc, request))
.flatMap(command -> cTaskService.cTask(command)
    .flatMapMany(event -> Mono.just(event).concatWith(Mono.justOrEmpty(event.getThrowable()).flatMap(Mono::error)))
    .cast(orEvent.class)
    .onErrorResume(throwable -> myFactory.createorEvent(or, throwable, command.getName()))
)
```